# ComponentDidMount returns value when page is loaded but when I refresh page it gives undefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, react-context

I am building an e-commerce app. When I click product I am redirecting to details page based on items id. Then based on this id I am calling function which is located in context. The problem is that when details page is loaded I am getting data but when I refresh that details page instead of data it gives me bunch of undefined. I am in checking `componentDidMount`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import withRouter from "../components/withRouter";
import { ProductContext } from "../context";

export default withRouter(
  class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        id: this.props.router.params.id,
        singleItem: [],
        loaded: false,
      };
      //this.getItem();

      this.getItem = this.getItem.bind(this);
    }
    static contextType = ProductContext;

    componentDidMount() {
    // when this executes first time . a.k.a page loads works//
    // than console.log values still match and "executed" still displays
    // but 3 lines below if can't return undefined 
      console.log(this.state.singleItem.length, this.state.id);
      if (this.state.singleItem.length === 0 && this.state.id) {
        const { getSingleProduct } = this.context;
        const item = getSingleProduct(this.state.id);
       
        this.getItem(item);

        console.log("executed");
      }
    }

    getItem = (item) => {
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          id: this.props.router.params.id,
          singleItem: item,
        };
      });
    };

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.singleItem);
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

The expression seems right but I am getting opposite result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I am getting undefined is componentdidMount  calls getSingleProduct. but when id is passed context state's array of product is empty.
This array is full when I am in main page when I click product It's still full but when I refresh The items are suddenly disappearing. after that I have no Idea what to do..

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see with the code is that of storing passed props in local state. It's a React anti-pattern and is prone to causing stale state/state synchronization issues. Consume props directly.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import withRouter from "../components/withRouter";
import { ProductContext } from "../context";

class Details extends Component {
  state = {
    singleItem: [],
    loaded: false,
  }

  static contextType = ProductContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { singleItem } = this.state;
    const { router } = this.props;

    if (!singleItem.length && router.params.id) {
      const { getSingleProduct } = this.context;
      const item = getSingleProduct(router.params.id);
   
      this.getItem(item);

      console.log("executed");
    }
  }

  getItem = (singleItem) => {
    this.setState({ singleItem });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.singleItem);
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Details);
```